# error="ingress class annotation is not equal to the expected by Ingress Controller"

Tags: redirect, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We are facing in Nginx ingress controller and all of sudden its stopped working and we saw below error in the log.

secure", UID:"8e7fa1f8-691d-472a-a6e8-e46f4cb12cb9", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"77273484", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I1024 00:15:51.789598       7 store.go:426] "Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="4600-mb/4600mb-private" error="ingress class annotation is not equal to the expected by Ingress Controller"

After we remove the URL redirection from the ingress resource , service got restored back normal.I am suspecting something is wrong in the ingress file. Can someone please help me , i am in the trouble.